# Cross domain with JSONP not working: permission issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display some movie posters on my web site by loading them from a different web site. I grabbed the URLs of the posters and saved them into a mySQL database. When the user looks for a poster the script will search the database and get the full URL via ajax and populate an IMG tag to display the picture.

I noticed that one of the two web sites where I get the links from returns "**You don't have permission to access...**". But if I copy the same link inside the browser address bar I can see the picture. After some research **I guessed that this is due to cross domain issue**. I read that the most common solution is JSONP so I managed to work out the following code. You may see that there are two links: the first link works, the second link (filmup.it) returns the permission error. (The issue is not due to the missing 'www').

**HTML code**

```
<input type="text" id="link" value="http://www.cinemadelsilenzio.it/images/film/poster/11469_big.jpg" />
<!-- <input type="text" id="link" value="http://filmup.leonardo.it/posters/loc/500/dieanotherday.jpg" /> -->
<button class="searchbutton" type="button">Vai</button>

<br />

<img id="poster" src=""/>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchbutton").click(function(){    
        var _text = document.getElementById("link").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'img.php',
            data: {parameter1: _text},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
            }
        });
    }); 
});

function jsonpCallback(data){
    $("#poster").attr("src", data);
}
</script>
```

**PHP code**

```
// let's suppose that here there's a mySQL code to retrieve the links
if (isset($_GET['parameter1']) && isset($_GET['callback'])) {
    $picture = $_GET['parameter1'];
    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($picture).");";
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just set the img `.src` to the link value directly?

Comment: @Jack. Please explain.

Comment: I mean `$('#poster').prop('src', _text)` inside the click handler instead of the `$.ajax()`.

Comment: The above code is simplified. As said I keep the links in a db that are retrieved upon a user search and displayed into my web site via ajax. With one link this works, with the other I get the permission error.

Comment: I don't see why you would get a permission error, because `img.php` is the same path, so unless there's something wrong with the script, the issue is somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: Please, if you have time to try, exchange the two links. You will see that with 'filmup.it' it does not work.

Comment: Dunno, maybe the other site has hotlink protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!** Finally I worked out by myself. Change the Jquery code above with the following:

```
$(".searchbutton").click(function(){    
    var _text = document.getElementById("link").value;
    $.get("img.php", {parameter1: _text }, 
        function(data) {
            $('#poster').html('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + data + '" />');
        }
    );
});
```

and change all of the PHP code above with the following:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($_GET["parameter1"]));
?>
```

DO NOT leave any space after `<?php` and before `?>`.

**--- If you use mySQL ---**

I noticed that if you need to retrieve data from a mySQL database before sending it to `file_get_contents` this will **not work** if you add the mySQL code inside the above PHP file. For example the following code will **not output** anything:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('posters', $db);
if (isset($_GET['parameter1'])) {
    $p = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['parameter1']);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM posters WHERE title = '".$p."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($row["Link"]));
}
```

I don't know why, but `file_get_contents` is not completed with the retrieved data from the db although `$row["Link"]` has the correct content. It appears that `$row["Link"]` is simply empty, but it's not.

You need to redirect the output to an other page. Change

```
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($row["Link"]));
```

with

```
header("location: image.php?link=".$row["Link"]);
```

The image.php file will be:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($_GET["link"]));
```

Hope this helps someone.